# Is there a JavaScript test framework that allows you to write parameterized UnitTest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

Is there a JavaScript test framework that allows you to write parameterized UnitTest.

Like Nunit.

```
[TestCase("condition1")]
[TestCase("condition2")]
```

Comment: A question like this would be much less disapproved if bringing “what I’ve found, and how it doesn’t fulfill the requirements” to the table..

Answer (score 0):

Jest framework has this option:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testeachtablename-fn-timeout

Comment: Thanks very much .
This is what I was looking for.